# Class diagram for Java method with parameters

Tags: java, methods, parameters, uml, class-diagram

I have a class with the method below. What is the correct way to write the method and its parameters in a Class Diagram?

```
public class Staff {
    public double calculatePackagesNeeded(double strippingNeeded, double strippingLength) {
        return (double)Math.ceil(strippingNeeded / strippingLength);
    }
}
```

I'm currently using this:

+calculatePackagesNeeded():double

but should it be this:

+calculatePackagesNeeded(double, double):double

Comment: What have you read to try to find the answer?

Comment: So, why don't you use it then?

Comment: @tgdavies I feel like I've read a lot, both here and on the web in general, and can't seem to find an example that shows what I'm looking for (or, more likely, I'm just not understanding how the examples I find would apply to what I'm asking).

If I was asked, this is what my current understanding is:
+getMethod():type //because it returns something
+setMethod():void //because it returns nothing
+workerMethod():type //no parameters, returns something
+workerMethod(type):type //1 parameters, returns something

Apologies if my question was bad in whatever way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In principle

According to the UML specs:

> An Operation is a BehaviorialFeature of an Interface, DataType, or Class. An Operation may be directly invoked on instances of its featuringClassifiers. The Operation **specifies** the name, type, **Parameters**, and Constraints for such invocations.

Going by the book, it should be:

```
+calculatePackagesNeeded(strippingNeeded : Real, strippingLength :Real):Real
```

because the primitive UML types are limited to `Integer`, `Boolean`, `String`, `UnlimitedNatural`, and `Real` and the parameter names is not optional. Nevertheless, if we assume a language-specific UML profile for java, and if we tolerate the paramter name hiding it could indeed be:

```
+calculatePackagesNeeded(double, double):double
```

### In practice

However, for high-level models, you do not necessarily need this level of details.  Also, in early stages of any OO modeling, operations and responsibilities may be identified for classes, before the details of the parameters are worked out. In these contexts you may well use:

```
+calculatePackagesNeeded():double
```

This simplification seems however acceptable imho, only if the other operations (at least of the same class) are shown this way too, because as soon as you'd have some real signatures in the model, the shortcut notation could create ambiguity.

Comment: typo "...is *not* part..."?

Comment: @tgdavies Indeed. Thanks! corrected.